# relationships between two MySQL tables problem

Tags: mysql, datatable, foreign-keys

I would like the column manager in the table section to automatically set the value to the id of the newly added worker if its column section is equal to the column `section_id` in the table `section`.

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
 emp_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 last_name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 position INT,
 section INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (emp_id));

CREATE TABLE section(
 section_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 manager INT,
 PRIMARY KEY (section_id));

CREATE TABLE position (
 position_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (position_id));

ALTER TABLE employee AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
ALTER TABLE position AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
ALTER TABLE section AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

INSERT INTO section (name) VALUES ('lighting');
select * from section;
+------------+----------+---------+
| section_id | name     | manager |
+------------+----------+---------+
|          2 | lighting |    NULL |
+------------+----------+---------+

INSERT INTO employee (name, last_name, section) VALUES ('James', 'Bond', 2);

select * from section;
+------------+----------+---------+
| section_id | name     | manager |
+------------+----------+---------+
|          2 | lighting |    NULL |
+------------+----------+---------+
```

How do you add `FOREIGN KEY` so that when you add James Bond, the column manager in the section table automatically changed the value from `null to James Bond's id`?

Comment: You don't. That would be a redundancy.

Comment: So all I can do is:
    ALTER TABLE section ADD FOREIGN KEY (manager) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;

and then:

    UPDATE section SET manager = 2 WHERE section_id = 2 AND manager = NULL;

Comment: ON UPDATE CASCADE it is not a solution?

Comment: You would not store this information. I'm not sure that I can be any clearer.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you